# Redirect website from https to http but browser said "too many redirect"

Tags: .htaccess

here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The problem is when I add this rule to my .htaccess file and reload the site it said me "too many redirect" and the site doesn't work. Why? How can i change https to http? I want to do this change only for a few week but i don't know how. Thanks

EDIT:

I change the code to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

but it still doesn't work

Comment: In your rule you miss $, should be something like RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L], try this if it helps

Comment: what does the $ serve for?

Comment: Its for anchors:   ^ -  Start of line anchor,  $ - End   of line anchor

Comment: You can learn a bit more of .htaccess file in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule

Comment: ok, thanks but it still doesn't work.

Comment: the problem is that chrome said me "too many redirect" and i don't know why

Comment: The matching pattern is not the issue here, the application is gready in this case, so that pattern _does_ match everything. But even if not: you do not use the captured payload anyway but use `%{REQUEST_URL}` in the target definition. Which is perfectly fine and does make sense! So actually a matching pattern like `^` would have exactly the same effect here.

Comment: The issue is that your host responds to _both_ protocols currently. Chrome (and many other browsers these days too) check whether a http ressource can also be reached using https (which is preferred for obvious reasons). So if you redirect to http then most likely the browser itself decides to redirect itself again to https and the loop starts...

Comment: But another issue is obvious here: it is not really possible to redirect from https to http. None of todays browsers will follow such a redirection, _except_ if the user explicitly insists in doing so. So the browser will clearly warn the user. Not sure if you see that warning and just forgot to mention it in the question or if you managed to finally accept that for your own browser and your own site... But in the end every user of your site will see that warning and most likely _not_ follow that redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^off$
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Or:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriterRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If that doesn't work, the browser is probably stopping it from redirecting back to http. Or, the browser is redirecting back to HTTPS after the redirect to HTTP, and the loop starts there.

Anyways, it is a **very bad idea** to redirect https to http. If an ssl cert is your issue, you can get one from LetsEncrypt for free :) For localhost, you can create your own self signed cert, and trust it in your pc.

You should actually be redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS usually, because security is needed.